Jest has different behavior in watch mode
I'm writing a extension for chrome omnibox. And I'm using jest to write testing, but I found that the behavior of npx jest and npx jest --watchAll are different.
Detailly, npx jest works fine and it indicate that my tests have passed, but while running in npx jest --watchAll it tells me that TypeError: chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion is not a function, and the calling of chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion is from my code, which means jest doesn't find chrome somehow.
I'm using sinon-chrome to mock the chrome, here is the jest.config.ts:
// jest.config.ts

import { type JestConfigWithTsJest } from "ts-jest";

const chrome = require("sinon-chrome");
const config: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  verbose: true,
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  globals: {
    chrome,
  },
};

export default config;


Please let me know if I missed anything about this question.
I think npx jest --watchAll has some specify logic that missed my chrome mock, but I don't know where it is. It'd be great if someone familiar with the relative config, thanks in advance.
